# Finding the determinant of a $4 \times 4$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm trying to find the determinant of this $4 \times 4$ matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}3&0&0&-2\\-3&0&-3&0\\0&3&0&-2\\0&-2&2&0\end{bmatrix}$$

I'm also trying to get it in lower triangular so that way i can multiply the diagonal. I did $R_2 = R_1 + R_2,$ then I did $R_2 = 2R_2 + 3R_3$ then $R_4 = R_4 + R_2$ then $R_4 = R_2 - R_4$ then finally: $R_4 = R_3 + 2R_4$ to get

$$\begin{bmatrix}3&0&0&-2\\0&-2&-1&-2\\0&0&6&-4\\0&0&0&-8\end{bmatrix}$$

to get the $\det(A) = 288$ , why is this incorrect??

Comment: Were you expecting $\det A = -72$, by chance?

Comment: Nope, I computed the product of the diagonal after obtaining lower triangular form of the matrix to get $(3)(-2)(6)(-8) = 288$ which is somehow wrong?

Comment: You did $R_4=R_2-R_4$, so you modified your determinant by a factor $-1$

Comment: How do I fix it @Jennifer

Comment: As Jennifer says, your row operations do not all preserve the determinant; in all, you've multiplied the determinant by $-4$ in row-reducing to triangular form, so the determinant should be $288/(-4) = -72$, which Antoine's answer confirms.

Comment: Where did i multiply any rows by $-4$ ?

Comment: @Shammy When you make a transform of the form : $R_i=bR_j-R_i$, you need to multiply your new determinant by $-1$.

Comment: Okay... so that still isn;t fixing it tho, that now makes my new determinant $-288$ insteaod of $288$

Comment: When it should be $-72$

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang How and *where* did i multiply anything in my matrix by $-4$??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$R_2=2R_2+3R_2$ multiplies the determinant by $2$; $R_4=R_3+2R_4$ multiplies by another $2$; $R_4=R_2-R_4$ multiplies it by $-1$. In each of these cases, you’ve combined two elementary row operations into one: multiplying a row by a scalar and adding a scalar multiple of one row to another. Of the two, only the latter operation preserves the determinant. The former multiplies the determinant by that scalar. If you divide $288$ by $-4$, you get $-72$, which is the correct answer.

Comment: THANK YOU AMD, finally someone who answers the actual QUESTION(s) I presented!!

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{vmatrix}3&0&0&\!-2\\\!-3&0&\!-3&0\\0&3&0&\!-2\\0&\!-2&2&0\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}3&0&0&\!-2\\0&0&\!-3&\!-2\\0&3&0&\!-2\\0&\!-2&2&0\end{vmatrix}=3\cdot\begin{vmatrix}0&\!-3&\!-2\\3&\;0&\!-2\\\!-2&2&\;0\end{vmatrix}=-72$$

Comment: What? It;s neither in Lower Triangular or Upper Triangular?

Comment: Also what is this form where you have all 0's in the diagonal??

Comment: @Shammy Expand along the first column and you'll see where the $-72$ comes from.

Comment: @Ed_4434 Not asking where the -72 comes from. I'm asking why the answer he gave is not in Upper Triangular *or* Lower Triangular but some other form I've never seen before

Comment: @Shammy The point isn't that it's in either of those two forms. IF you're looking to find the determinant by putting it into either upper or lower triangular forms then this answer is technically not relevant. However the point of THIS particular answer is that it's as easy as elimnating the $-3$ under the first pivot and then expanding along that column. :)

Comment: Exactly but you just hit what I'm saying right on the money. I'm looking for it in the methods that have been taught, not some new method that is irrelevant. I don't even know what Antoine is doing

Comment: @Shammy Antoine used the Laplace_expansion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion Please have a look at it. It is not very difficult.

Comment: Antoine wrote no steps or explanation

Comment: Then this answer isn't relevant to your question @Shammy :) I refer you to the new answer that somebody else has given.